# servidor PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

debo crear una base de datos con PostgreSQL pero necesito que 2 personas mas entren a mi base de datos ¿es posible?.
Lo he intentado con wamp he estado buscando y configurando y junto con PhpPgAdmin al momento de iniciar sesión me devuelve al inicio, ya se ha configurado dentro de todo "$conf['extra_login_security'] = false;" y se han abierto los puertos correspondientes.

Programas Ocupados:

- PostgreSQL
- PhpPgAdmin
- Wampserver

Comment: ¿Cómo necesitas que entren? digo al final es un tema mas de configuración de postgres que de php o wamp

Comment: @DrakoRod Hola la necesidad es poder trabajar todos en la misma base de postgreeSQL, ejemplo la tipica base de datos en PHPMyadmin que pueden entrar varias personas para poder trabajar con dicha base, se entiende?